# Player.io + MongoDb

Tags: actionscript-3, mongodb, multiplayer, player.io

Does anyone have heard is there any way to connect player.io (http://playerio.com/) with MongoDb (http://www.mongodb.org/) ?

I know that player.io has BigDb (http://playerio.com/features/bigdb/) in its paid features pack but I would like to use my own database by MongoDb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDB is fully accessible using the free package.

You could load data from your own database using the multiplayer [Web Class](http://playerio.com/documentation/reference/multiplayer/playerio.gamelibrary.web). However access to said Web class is a paid feature and you would need to create a web service for your MongoDB instance.